# Android Google Play Services Library, Analytics strange output

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am getting a funny output in my console when using Google Analytics via Google Play Services Library. This only happens when I send the first Tracker send.

> 03-31 13:07:27.426: I/dalvikvm(17463): Could not find method
>   android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from
>   method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzg

And

> 03-31 13:19:01.386: W/dalvikvm(19440): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 442: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller
>   ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;

I don't appear to be receiving data in analytics although it says that it sends the hit. I am using Analyticsv4 through Google Play Services SDK. I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue crop up on Apr 2 and have resolved today on one of my devices.

Samsung NOTE 3: I manually updated GooglePlayServices to 7.0.99 (4.4.4) and now it's working (No more GPS messages exactly as you've stated above).
Samsung NOTE 4: I left at GPS 7.0.86 (4.4.4) and it's still not working - same messages you have above.
Nexus: No issues as it was updated already to .99.

Thankfully GPS is updated frequently - I'm thinking to add code to check to see if GPS is at latest release level if we get an error (in my case a crash for the NOTE4). Not sure if I can do this but may be worth a try.

Comment: How did you update Google Play Services? I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: @NJGUY         probably just adding a line to build.gradle:     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0' for example?

Comment: @NJGUY you update through google play or through the devices settings in the app list. The OP is talking about differnt devices running differnt versions...